# Create URL from an ObjectID

Tags: rally

How do I dynamically create a URL for to embedded a link for a UserStory record as compared to hardcoding the string?

```
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        model: 'UserStory',
        fetch: ['ObjectID'],
        listeners: {
            load: function (store, records) {
                Ext.each(records, function(record) {
                      var ref = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/14139205418d/detail/userstory/" + record.get('ObjectID');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In an app example in this [github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/iterations-within-release/blob/master/App.js) I get the project from the [app context](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/context):

```
var project = this.getContext().getProject();
this._projectOid = project.ObjectID;
```

and then consturct the URL without having to hardcode the project's ObjectID:

```
return '<a href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/' + that._projectOid + '/detail/iteration/' + record.get('ObjectID') + '" target="_blank">' + record.get('Name') + '</a>';
```

This example is for iteration but you may adapt it for a user story.

UPDATE: per Mark's comment, it is not even necessary to traverse the context to get project's OID to get to the userstory's details page - the redirect will take care of it automatically.

Comment: Note that the project OID is not required. The following form: https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/userstory/12345678910
is valid for any rally artifact, and will automatically re-direct to the project of concern.

Comment: @Mark W True, thank you, the redirect link will automatically include project oid.

Comment: I did not realize that the project was not necessary.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.nav.Manager-method-getDetailUrl

```
var url = Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(record);
```

Comment: I had tried your function yesterday and again today and I receive and error of "Cannot read property 'Manager' of undefined"

Comment: Which version of the sdk are you using?  2.0rc3 was just released recently- that was the version I linked to in the docs above.  It should be supported in 2.0rc1 and above.